# Is `gem update --system` broken for ruby < 2.3?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Today after the upgrade of [rubygems-update](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update) the `gem update --system` with ruby older than 2.3 has started to fail permanently with the next error:

```
# gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-3.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
    rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/local/bundle/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.6
# ruby --version
ruby 2.1.9p490 (2016-03-30 revision 54437) [x86_64-linux]
```

Is there any way to do it or it's just a new reality and I have to adjust any place which has used `gem update` to it?

Comment: First stop for things like this is the [Rubygems issues](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues) page, presuming this is actually a bug and not a limitation of newer versions of Rubygems which it appears to be. For historical versions of Ruby you're stuck with historical versions of Rubygems.

Comment: Ruby 2.3.0 was released in 2015, so presumably the Rubygems team is moving forward and cutting support for much older versions like 2.1. Ruby updates quickly enough now that updating Rubygems itself manually like this is no longer really necessary. The update procedure is a by-product of the 1.9.2-1.9.3 era where Ruby wasn't evolving as quickly as Rubygems itself was.

Comment: thank you for a link, @tadman. I'll create an issue. Unfortunately, the 2.1.9 version is the part of puppet 4 and each module should be checked for compatibility with it.  https://github.com/puppetlabs/pdk-templates/blob/master/config_defaults.yml#L71

Comment: The permanent link to the [broken check](https://github.com/puppetlabs/pdk-templates/blob/12824103f4b054d2672e3f1ed1f4b9689643ea34/config_defaults.yml#L71)

Comment: Puppet really needs to get with the program and upgrade to 2.3 as a baseline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, there is an [issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2534). The requirement for ruby newer or equal to 2.3 is a new reality and everyone has to adopt the project to it. E.g. https://github.com/puppetlabs/pdk-templates/pull/171.

**TL;DR**: `gem update --system 2.7.8`